# React-table api filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-table

I have a question regarding React-Table and it's filtering pagination implementation.

I need to build a dynamic data table for a project I'm working on, from my understanding of React-Table the filtering and pagination features only work on a complete set of data that is rendered in the table already, with the data I am working with in my project all filtering and pagination is dealt with at the API level via query parameters so I'm not sure React-Table will be a good fit for my needs but I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Thanks in advance